# Silverlight binding in a DataGridRowGroupHeader doesn't update when DataSource changes

Tags: silverlight, xaml, datagrid, binding, grouping

I have a Binding in a inline style for the DataGridRowGroupHeader like this.

```
<sdk:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
     <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
        <Setter Property="Template">
     <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
                           <TextBlock Margin="4,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource headerConverter}}" />
```

The DataGrid ItemsSource is Bound to a PageCollectionView containing an observable collection, which is grouped by a property in the collection. When I update the collection the rows of the grid change, but the binding in the GroupHeader does not change.

Is there a different way to bind this or a way to force the UI to update?

This is the converter I'm using on the Header binding:

```
 public class GroupHeaderConverter2 : IValueConverter {

public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
var cvg = value as CollectionViewGroup;

return string.Format("({0} Remaining)", cvg.Items.Count((i) => ((CheckListEventDefinition)i).Complete == false && ((CheckListEventDefinition)i).Required == true));
}

public object ConvertBack(object value,
        System.Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture) {
return null;
}
```

}

Got this to work by changing the source collection to my own extended ObservableCollection that also monitors the elements for PropertyChanged and then raises the CollectionChanged Event.

```
/// <summary> this collection is also monitoring the elements for changes so when PropertyChanged fires on any element, it will raise the CollectionChanged event</summary>
public class ObservableCollectionEx<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public ObservableCollectionEx(ObservableCollection<T> regularCollection) {
        if (regularCollection != null) {
            foreach (var item in regularCollection) {
                this.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public void RaiseCollectionChanged() {
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        Unsubscribe(e.OldItems);
        Subscribe(e.NewItems);
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
    }

    protected override void ClearItems() {
        foreach (T element in this)
            element.PropertyChanged -= handlePropertyChanged;

        base.ClearItems();
    }

    private void Subscribe(IList iList) {
        if (iList == null) return;
        foreach (T element in iList)
            element.PropertyChanged += handlePropertyChanged;
    }

    private void Unsubscribe(IList iList) {
        if (iList == null) return;
        foreach (T element in iList)
            element.PropertyChanged -= handlePropertyChanged;
    }

    private void handlePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are binding directly to the object and not to a property with a `Path`.  If you bind without a `Path` the binding will never update because there is no `PropertyChanged` event to notify the UI that the binding has changed.  The simplest change is to change your binding to `{Binding Items, Converter={StaticResource headerConverter}}` and then cast value in your converter directly to `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<object>`.

If you need more flexibility then this I believe you will have to implement your own `ICollectionView` with a custom `CollectionViewGroup`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I actually got it to work though by switching the underlying collection to my own extended ObservableCollection that also monitors the elements it contains for PropertyChanged and then raises CollectionChanged.

Answer (score 0):

Stephan

I follow your solution with a difference:
- i use a parameter
- i use a datagridcell

but when i modify my datasource the datagroupheader doesn't change.
`<data:DataGridCell Content="{Binding Items,Converter={StaticResource myConverterBnc}, ConverterParameter=Fattura,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Foreground="White" Width="113"/>`